# SEL selMethod = @selector(function_name:);?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What actually is a @selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482344/what-actually-is-a-selector)

What does the following statement do?

```
SEL selMethod = @selector(function_name:);
```

(where, type of SEL is objc_selector.)
Any guess?

Comment: See also: [What's the difference between a method and a selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5608476/557219)

Comment: See also: [What actually is a @selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3482344/557219)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on Selectors. They are used alot when you need to refer to class methods. For example, when dynamically deciding what to call at runtime.

Comment: Both class and instance methods.