# What's a selector?

Tags: objective-c

[Stanford University, CS193p, Lecture 3](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/lectures/Lecture%203_0.pdf), Page 45

I read this too

[The Objective-C Programming documentation, Selectors](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocSelectors.html)

Still can't understand any of both

Can someone explain it more clearly? It would be better if it's in a C/C++ way :)

Comment: This question is way too broad. A selector is just the name for an Objective-C method. It has the type SEL, and you can make them using `@selector`.

Comment: Yea.. Figured out how idiot I was after few minutes, but thought it may have another meaning or so, so I left the question

Thanks Yuji anyway :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What actually is a @selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482344/what-actually-is-a-selector)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: it's a method name.

In Objective-C, a method call works differently than in, say, C++. Ever method call in Objective-C really is a call to the C function `objc_msgSend` or a variant of it. This function then decides how to actually make the method call. The first argument to this function is the object pointer (`self`), the second is the selector (`_cmd`, the method name). Additional arguments are the method arguments. Now `objc_msgSend` looks up which compiled method needs to be called for the selector and then jumps to it. So the selector "selects" which method of the object gets called.

Comment: In other words, selector is like something which "saves" a method so you can make an object do it. Right?

Comment: Not quite. You see, each method is actually compiled into a C function. But you can also create them at runtime. Both are called implementations and have the type `IMP`, and this is what is finally called by `objc_msgSend`. You can now imagine that each object has a kind of table, with selectors as keys and implementations as values.   Again, the selector "selects" which implementation needs to be called.

Comment: How does it "select" it then?

Comment: So you got the table with implementations. You pass an object and a selector to `objc_msgSend`, which then looks in the table which implementation is to be called for the selector. Like, `imp = [implementationsTable objectForKey:selector];` (of course, that's not how it really is done but it helps to imagine it that way).

Comment: I never dealt with objc_msgSend by the way -,-

But isn't that made automatically by the compiler? I mean that each method has an implementation, what's the selector's role then?

And answering with examples (simplest as you can please :) ) would be much better

Comment: You don't have to deal with `objc_msgSend` and shouldn't. I was just telling you what compiler is actually doing with a message call like `[self foo]` so you can hopefully gain a better understanding what a selector is :-) In this case, the selector is "foo". In other words: it's the method name. If you call `[self foo:alpha bar:beta]` the selector is `foo:beta:` and is used to look up the implementation to call. Sorry, I can't make it any simpler than that.