# how to call method by a button which is created through coding

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am fresh in iphone..i have created one button and through coding and want to call   a method by that button what should i do please help me..

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 150, 44); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
[myButton setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// add targets and actions
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// add to a view
[myview addSubview:myButton];
```

Comment: Just a quick comment. This is iOS, on an iPhone. There is no "clicking" of buttons. Although it makes no difference I'd prefer to use `buttonTapped`. "Click" has no relevance to iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the question itself

```
// add targets and actions
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

this line **added a action to the button** which is in `self` with action name `buttonClicked:` for the controlevent  `touchUpInside`

so when a button is touchupInside it will execute the method buttonClicked

Therefore

```
- (void)buttonClicked: (UIButton *)sender
{
 // do whatever you want to do here on button click event
}
```

will get executed on button action

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)buttonClicked: (UIButton *)sender
{
 // do stuff
}
```

Comment: kya hia ye, jra or btao??

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [UIControl documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

**action :** `A selector identifying an action message. It cannot be NULL.`

You are passing `@selector(buttonClicked:)` as action. `@selector()` is a compiler directive to turn whatever's inside the parenthesis into a `SEL`. A `SEL` is a type to indicate a method name, but not the method implementation.[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3482356/944634) so implement `-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender` in your class.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)buttonClicked: (UIButton *)sender
{
 // do whatever you want to do here on button click event
}
```